# How to restrict access to partners by create_uid

Tags: security, odoo-10

I need to limit user access only to partners added himself.
That's what I have made:
security.xml  of my module:

```
<odoo>
  <data noupdate="1">
    <record model="ir.rule" id="partner_access_user_rule">
      <field name="name">Parners only for editors</field>
      <field name="model_id" ref="base.model_res_partner"/>
      <field name="domain_force"> [('create_uid','=',user.id)] </field>
      <field name="groups" eval="[(4,ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
    </record>
  </data>
</odoo>
```

**Update** I have changed ref="base.model_res_partner" as Lucas told, and my module have installed, but the rule didn't uppear in settings > security>"record rules" and didn't apply. I've added record rule via web interface and it works. How I to export it to apply to my module? The record rule settings I've added to question.

Export file:

```
id,"perm_create","perm_unlink","perm_read","perm_write","domain_force","groups/id","name","model_id/id"
__export__.ir_rule_97,"True","True","True","True","[('create_uid','=',user.id)]","base.group_user","Partners only for editors","account.model_res_partner"
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is looking for the model `res.partner` on `mail.partner.access`, when it should look on `base`.

Try the following:

```
<field name="model_id" ref="base.model_res_partner"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. After changing security settings like you told, my module have installed. But the rule didn't uppear in settings > security>"record rules" and didn't apply. I've added record rule via web interface and it works. How to export it to apply to my module? The record rule settings and export file I've added to question.

Answer (score 0):

If your row-level access rule doesn't work, create and test it using Odoo interface, export it to csv and change your original XML. Or create xml directly from CSV (look at attached picture[image]). In my case  I've found mistake: **model_id** should refer to **base.model_res_partner**

---